# Pandas merging on different size dataframes based on one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 different sizes of dataframes.

On df1, I have `date`, `time`, `username`, `email address`, `phone number`, `duration` from logs. But `email address` and `phone number` is just columns with empty string.

On df2, I have all the `username`, `email address` and `phone number` from the database.

How can I merged df2 into df1 based on the username?
Meaning to say the size of df1 will stays the same, but the `email address` and `phone number` columns will be populated. Of course with the matching data from df2

Assuming `username` is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with left join and parameter `suffixes`, lastr remove original columns `email address` and `phone number` (with `_`):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'username':list('abccdd'),
         'email address':[''] * 6,
         'phone number':[''] * 6,
         'duration':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
})
print (df1)
  username email address phone number  duration
0        a                                    5
1        b                                    3
2        c                                    6
3        c                                    9
4        d                                    2
5        d                                    4

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'username':list('abcd'),
         'email address':['a@a.sk','b@a.sk','c@a.sk','d@a.sk'],
         'phone number':range(4)
})
print (df2)
  username email address  phone number
0        a        a@a.sk             0
1        b        b@a.sk             1
2        c        c@a.sk             2
3        d        d@a.sk             3
```

---

```
df = (df1.merge(df2, on='username', how='left', suffixes=('_',''))
        .drop(['email address_','phone number_'], axis=1)
        .reindex(columns=df1.columns))
print (df)
  username email address  phone number  duration
0        a        a@a.sk             0         5
1        b        b@a.sk             1         3
2        c        c@a.sk             2         6
3        c        c@a.sk             2         9
4        d        d@a.sk             3         2
5        d        d@a.sk             3         4
```

Another solution with [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) for all columns names without defined in list and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same ordering like in `df1` of columns:

```
c = df1.columns.difference(['email address','phone number'])
df = df1[c].merge(df2, on='username', how='left').reindex(columns=df1.columns)

print (df)
  username email address  phone number  duration
0        a        a@a.sk             0         5
1        b        b@a.sk             1         3
2        c        c@a.sk             2         6
3        c        c@a.sk             2         9
4        d        d@a.sk             3         2
5        d        d@a.sk             3         4
```

Comment: Thanks! the 2nd one is much better that I do not need to reorder my column again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
df = df1[['username', 'date', 'time', 'duration']].merge(df2, left_on='username', right_on='username')
```

Example:
df1

```
   date  duration email address phone number   time username
0  2015         5                             14:00       aa
1  2016        10                             16:00       bb
```

df2

```
  email address   phone number username
0          rrr@         333444       aa
1           tt@         555533       bb
```

Output:

```
  username  date   time  duration email address   phone number
0       aa  2015  14:00         5          rrr@         333444
1       bb  2016  16:00        10           tt@         555533
```